# How to change a Kivy App's configuration file default directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to change the directory where my Kivy App's `'%(appname)s.ini'` file is saved.

I can get the current directory with `get_application_config()`, but even if I change the `defaultpath` attribute nothing happens.  I also tried to set the `'KIVY_HOME'` environment variable but I must be doing something wrong.

#### Code

```
#These are the three methods I tried
#Method 1 change KIVY_HOME environment at beginning before importing App class
import kivy
import os, plyer
con_change = plyer.storagepath.get_documents_dir()
os.environ['KIVY_HOME'] = con_change + '/'

#Method 2 change KIVY_HOME environment within App class
import kivy
import os, plyer
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ConfigParserProperty

class LoginApp(App):
    title = 'Login'
    us_er = ConfigParserProperty('', 
                    'mylog', 'uname', 'app')
    p_wd = ConfigParserProperty('', 
                    'mylog', 'pwd', 'app')
    con_change = plyer.storagepath.get_documents_dir()
    def build(self):
        self.config.export KIVY_HOME = self.con_change + '/%(appname)s.ini' #gives invalid syntax
        up = self.config.items('mylog')
        return TheLogger()
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('mylog', {
            'uname': '',
            'pwd': ''})

#Method 3 try to set defaultpath with get_application_path function
import kivy
import os, plyer
from kivy.app import App

class LoginApp(App):
    title = 'Login'
    us_er = ConfigParserProperty('', 
                    'mylog', 'uname', 'app')
    p_wd = ConfigParserProperty('', 
                    'mylog', 'pwd', 'app')
    con_change = plyer.storagepath.get_documents_dir()
    def build(self):
        self.get_application_config(defaultpath= self.con_change + '/%(appname)s.ini')

        up = self.config.items('mylog')
        return TheLogger()
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('mylog', {
            'uname': '',
            'pwd': ''})
```

I want to be able to set the directory for the `'%(appname)s.ini'` file outside the `'KIVY_HOME'` directory tree?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I did try your suggestion.  I get an ```AttributeError``` that my App class has no attribute ```get_config_file_name()```.  I checked the docs I cannot find such an attribute for  the App class or ```ConfigParser```.   Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html#kivy.config.ConfigParser.read), if you read a config file at the start of your app, that same config file will be used for the `Config.write()` method. So, if (at the top of your Python file) you do:

```
from kivy.config import Config
import os.path

def get_config_file_name():
    # return any file name here
    return str(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'myApp.ini'))

Config.read(get_config_file_name())
```

then do any `Config.set` (or anything else), then simply do a `Config.write()` to save the changes to the config file.

Comment: okay now I see what you meant, write a custom function that ```read``` from a newly created ```filename.ini``` and ```write``` to it.  Thank you.    This does actually create a new .ini file, but it does not contain the default section created in my ```build_config``` function.  The .ini file contains all kivy's default graphic ect. settings.  Do you know how to create a .ini file that only contains the section created in my ```build_config``` function?

Comment: You can just use `Config.setdefaults()` (instead of `config.setdefaults()`) to write to the `Config` file that was opened by the `Config.read()`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That solved it.  What is interesting is that your answer refers to the ```ConfigParser``` object with name 'kivy'.  While the ```build_config``` function  uses the ```ConfigParser``` object with name 'app' to build the sections.  If I at the beginning of the python script point the ```Config``` object to ```ConfigParser``` object with name 'app' for e.g. ```Config = ConfigParser('app')``` and then follow your answer, will that create a .ini file with only the ```build_config``` function values?

Comment: No, it does not work to point the ```Config``` object to the ```ConfigParse('app')``` object.  The .ini file inside the app directory is once again used!  But what does create a .ini file in another directory which contains only my ```build_config``` function values, is by pointing the   ```Config``` object at the beginning of my script to some new unique ```ConfigParse('unique_name')``` object.  Taking into consideration this nugget and @John Anderson's answer I can now create a .ini file anywhere with any default info I need a user to use after closing the App.